# Constructing a graph from adjacency matrix in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

So I'm trying to construct a graph using igraph and an adjacency matrix that I have. It's a symmetrical matrix with ones where there should be an edge between two nodes and zeros where there is no connection. I'm using the code below to generate it:

```
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency(adjacency)
igraph.plot(g, layout = 'kk')
```

My adjacency matrix is type

```
numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix
```

But I tried to convert it to a list and an array and still get the same error:

```
TypeError: Error while converting adjacency matrix
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Adjacency method](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Adjacency) of igraph.Graph expects a matrix of the type [igraph.datatypes.Matrix](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.datatypes.Matrix-class.html), not a numpy matrix.

igraph will convert a list of lists to a matrix. Try using

```
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency(adjacency.astype(bool).tolist())
```

where `adjacency` is your numpy matrix of zeros and ones.